# Signature of Bilinear Forms

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, bilinear-form

Let $B : \mathbb{R}^4 × \mathbb{R}^4 → \mathbb{R}$ be a non-degenerate bilinear form and let $T : \mathbb{R}^4 → \mathbb{R}^4$ be a linear transformation. We denote by $T^∗$ the linear transformation which satisfies the condition $B(T(v),w)=B(v,T^∗(w))$ for all v, w ∈ V . Prove or disprove the following :

1. If $B$ has signature $(3,1)$ and if $T^∗ = T$, then for any $v ∈ V$ such that $T^2(v) = 0$, then $T(v) = 0$.

If $B$ is negative definite then I can prove this by $B(T(v),T(v))=B(v,T^*(T(v)))=B(v,T^2(v))=B(v,0)=0$ which implies $T(v)=0$. But I am not able to prove the case when $B$ has signature $(3,1)$ or $(2,2)$.

Comment: Since we talk about signature of B , B must be symmetric. Under the given hypothesis we must prove that Ker T and Im T are independent. Can you give some more context to the problem. Where is it taken from? It’s an interesting problem. But there are so many hidden questions. Does $T^*$ exist? Because when B is an inner product then $T^*$ exists. But for a bilinear form?

Comment: @LawrenceMano This problem was given by my professor as a practice end-term exam. Such a $T^*$ always exists, right? Just take $T=T^*$. This was a trivial case which is used in this problem. My professor tells me that this problem is based on some problem from the book M. Artin.